# React Router in separate files

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm trying to add routes to my react project. I have three separate components:

Window.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SideBar from "../SideBar/SideBar";
import MainBody from "../MainBody/MainBody";
import  { BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";

class Window extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
        <Router>
                <SideBar />
                <MainBody />
        </Router>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Window
```

SideBar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import  { BrowserRouter as Link} from "react-router-dom";

class SideBar extends Component {
     render() {
         return(

            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
         );
     }
}

export default SideBar;
```

MainBody.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from "./Home/Home";
import About from "./About/About";
import  { BrowserRouter as Route} from "react-router-dom";

class MainBody extends component {
     render() {
         return(
            <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}>
            </div>
         );
     }
}

export default MainBody;
```

So basically, when I click one of my links in SideBar, I want to transition to that link in my Main Body (the Home and About just display their titles). However, When I run this, my Window, MainBody, and SideBar components work but my Home and About components do not get displayed. I've properly imported the router components into each component file. If I place the Routes from MainBody into the Window component, they get displayed (Not sure if the router links work with it though). Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Can you please edit the code examples to let us know what is which file. Add exports and imports. Meybe link the codesandbox with example what is not working.

Comment: Hey there, I've updated the code snippets to include file names, exports and imports!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few typos in that snippets, dunno ifit was made when rewriting or u have it in your codebase, but be careful about them (component instead of Component, wrongly writtern render function with multiple elements returned etc).

```
import  { BrowserRouter as Link} from "react-router-dom";
```

Theese imports are also wrong, You have to import Link not something as Link. You are only renaming import BrowserRouter to Link.

```
import  { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

And same for Route.

Here is example [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7wqv156jox) . Let me know if that is what you wanted.